# Ethereum Contract Questions

Tags: ethereum, smartcontracts

So I've been looking deeper into Eathereum smart contracts and just had some questions about it (please get ready for noob questions)

1. When a contract is made so is the new token. Is the comtract held only in the contract address or also within the actual token itself. So each individual token holds the smart contract source code?
2. I've seen people say that contracts are safe because you can easily read source code before interacting with a smart contract. I assume they mean before you send coins to that address etc. this loops into the first questions because if the contract is within the token itself then what stops users from sending a coin to an address and activating that contract before source code gets read?
3. I understand contracts are primarily programmed in JavaScript first. What level of programming on JavaScript do you need to be to start programming smart contracts let's say simple contracts and not high level complicated.

I'll leave it at that for now.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I'll start with the easiest:

3. Ethereum smart contracts are programmed in Solidity or some other languages, but not JavaScript. You can interact with a contract using JavaScript though, with a library like web3.js.

2+1. Tokens are held within contracts ("token contracts"), not the other way round. If I made a token called TOK, how much TOK everyone had would be recorded inside a single contract (the "TOK contract") on the blockchain. Each token does not hold the contract code.